# Can I compare current month to previous month, day to day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I compare current month to previous month, day to day?

I'm due to create a report that compares the current month to the previous month but the code I've written only has volumes and values in one column. Ideally I'd have last months data  in one column and this months data in another column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: care to show us  "**code I've written**"

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Break your problem into pieces that you can do. First, write a query that will generate the values you want to compare for a single day. Then for every day within a range.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Day to day comparison? How will you compare the 31st day of a given month with the previous one?

Comment: @celsoap7 He won't? He will compare the rest and this one wold be data for 31th and nulls in the rest of the table? Same goes for February ;)

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you want to compare rows of the same table, you have to join the table to itself and give it to distinct aliases (here `A` and `B`):

```
SELECT A.Value - B.Value As Difference, ...
FROM
    myTable A
    INNER JOIN myTable B
        ON A.theDate = DATEADD(month, 1, B.theDate);
```

Here the A table represents the current month where as B represents the previous month. I assume that the dates do not contain times and that you have pure dates (i.e. time = 00:00:00). However, if you have times, you can truncate them with `CAST(theDate As Date)`.

You might have to add other conditions to the join ON-clause, like `AND A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID` to get the right pairing of rows. Also add a where clause, if you want to restrict the date range.